# Prevent XML files ending with <culture> in name to be generated as a resource file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio

Whenever I add `i18n.en.xml` or alike (just has to end with `<culture>.xml`) and compile my project, the file is compiled into `en/<Assembly>.resources.dll`, even though, I just wanted simply to embed it as a resource within the main assembly alone.

I have set it's **Build Action** to `Embedded Resource`.

If I rename it to `en.i18n.xml` (Making sure that it's still set as `Embedded Resource`), it gets properly embedded without creating extra assemblies. With properly, I mean, it can be seen by `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`.

How do I overcome this? It seems to be hardcoded in VS, that if the file is an XML and ends with a culture name associated to it, that it gets created as a `resources.dll`.

For testing purposes, I just added `test.xml` and set it to be Embedded Resource - got embedded properly. Renaming it to `test.en.xml` and recompiling, it's appended to `en/*.resources.dll`

Comment: No `*.resx`. I have handcrafted the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour for VS that (I guess) can't be overriden. Any file (not just XML) with build action `Embedded Resource` with name mask `*.<culture-code>.*` will be packed in sattelite assemblies. I guess your best option is to rename files.